# Installed Xfce4 on Debian - Now it doesn't work after reboot

Tags: debian, gnome, xfce

I installed XFCE 4 all went well. I could logout and login and change between different desktop environment. However when I shut down my computer and booted it up. I get an error from GNOME 3 that "something went wrong".

Then I tried installing xdm so I could get around this. And then I tried uninstall GNOME 3 with these command:

```
aptitude purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep gnome | cut -f 1`
aptitude -f install
aptitude purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f 1`
aptitude -f install
```

They couldn't find any so it couldn't be uninstalled.

Now I don't know what to check. I've looked through this documentation thorough: https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce . Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, you think you have GNOME 3, or part of GNOME 3, installed, and you want to remove it? And can you post the exact error message, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get to xdm and select the Xfce desktop before logging in. If I remember correctly there is a selection menu in top right of screen at the xdm login screen. I'm assuming you didn't select that before?